# Can I access view property in {{#with}} scope?

Tags: ember.js

I want to toggle visibility of element in {{#with}} scope, depending on the value of view's property.
I can access to view property in {{action}} in {{#with}}, but I can not access to view property in {{#with}.

Below is a sample program.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-0.9.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var App = Em.Application.create();
  App.Test = Em.View.extend({
    content: {
      description: 'names',
      names: [{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'john'}]
    },
    viewDetail: false,
    toggleDetail: function() {
      this.set('viewDetail', true);
    }
  })        
</script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view App.Test}}
    {{#with content}}
      {{description}}<br/>
      {{#each names}}
        {{name}}
      {{/each}}
      <br/>
      <button {{action toggleDetail}}>toggle Detail</button> <!-- can access toggleDetail -->
      {{#if viewDetail}} <!-- but can not access viewDetail... -->
        …detail Description...
      {{/if}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

Can I access to view property in {{#with}} scope ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#with` modifies the Handlebars context. You can go back up a level by using `../`.

Give this a try:

```
{{#if ../viewDetail}}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get back down a level while in the {{#if}} block?

Comment: @Fadi, you'd just prefix your properties with `content.` or add a new `with` block.